# Recurssion issue in generating permutation in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation, recurrence

i have two n in c++ and i want to generate permutation of the numbers in those vectors in such a way for each permutation of the first vector i have all the permutations of all the other vectors.
Say i have two vectors with number 2 9 and the other vector will be 5 6. then my result should be...

1. 2 9 5 6
2. 2 9 6 5
3. 9 2 5 6
4. 9 2 6 5

means that the total number of permutations i have got will be 
total perms = (# of permutations of the 1st vector  times number of permutations of the second vector times number of permutations of the third vector and so on).

I have written the below code and i am struck in to recursion stack... It is actually printing 6 times for the case of  2 vectors each have the size of 2 each.

```
mySwap(int *x, int *y){
int temp;
temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
*y = temp;
}
```

swaps the two int elements

```
void myPerm(vector<vector<int>> myItems, int start, int end,int     vectorIndex){
int j;
if(start == end){
    for(int k = vectorIndex +1; k < items.size(); ++k){
        myPerm(myItems, 0, myItems[k].size()-1,k);
    }
    for(int z = 0; z < myItems.size(); ++z){
        for(int l = 0; l < myItems[z].size(); ++z){
            std::cout << myItems[z][l];
        }
    }
}
else{
    for(int j = start; j <= end; j++){
        mySwap(&myItems[vectorIndex][start],&myItems[vectorIndex][j]);
        myPerm(myItems,start + 1, end,vectorIndex);
        mySwap(&myItems[vectorIndex][start],&myItems[vectorIndex][j]);

    }   

}
}
```

above code that generates permutations recursively...

```
int main(){
vector<vector<int>> myItems;
int k = 0;
for(int i =0; i < 2; ++i){
    myItems.push_back(vector<int>);
}
for(int j =0; j < 2; ++j){
    myItems[i].push_back(k++);
}

myPerm(items,0,items[0].size()-1,0);
return;
}
```

my main function.

Please give me some hint or solve this this for the generic case as the above code prints the permutations for the six which originally should be 4 times.

Thanks

Comment: Your `mySwap` function is missing `*x = *y` after the `temp = *x`.

Comment: Why are you writing `mySwap` when you could just use `std::swap`?

Comment: Also, why using `myPerm` when you could just use `std::next_permutation`?

Comment: mySwap function is corrected now actually i have not copy pasted code from my original source file thats y i missed that statement. Any ideas about recurssion problem

Comment: @AbdulSamad, parameter `myItems` is defined as vector, but should actually be a reference to vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the ideas specially for the STL function next_permutation. I don't know it earlier.

I was able to write the code i want it correctly...

Here is my code

```
void perm(std::vector<std::vector <int>> &items, int level){
if(level == 0){
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < items[i].size(); j++)
      std::cout << items[i][j];
std::cout<<std::endl;


    while(next_permutation(items[level].begin(), items[level].end())){
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < items[i].size(); j++)
              std::cout << items[i][j];
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
else{

    if(level > 0)
    perm(items,level-1);
    while(next_permutation(items[level].begin(), items[level].end())){
        if(level > 0)
        perm(items,level-1);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This code could be prettier, but more importantly observe the parameter `items`. Currently it is vector, so for each call to function `perm` the whole vector of vectors is copied. You should place there one ampersand sign (&), and turn parameter `items` into **reference** to vector: `std::vector<std::vector <int>>& items`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is not a homework you can simply use stl algorithm **[next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)**  instead of what you have.

This is the code for your sample input.

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> v1 , v2 , v3;
    v1.push_back( 2 );
    v1.push_back( 9 );
    v2.push_back( 5 );
    v2.push_back( 6 );

    std::sort( v1.begin() , v1.end() );
    std::sort( v2.begin() , v2.end() );

    do 
    {   
        v3 = v2;

        do 
        {
            std::for_each( v1.begin() , v1.end() , [](int x) { std::cout << x << " ";} );
            std::for_each( v3.begin() , v3.end() , [](int x) { std::cout << x << " ";} );
            std::cout << std::endl;
        } 
        while ( std::next_permutation(v3.begin() , v3.end() ) );
    } 
    while ( std::next_permutation(v1.begin() , v1.end() ) );

    return 0;
}
```

This does it for two vectors... I am sure you can generalize it further.

Comment: This solution works only for two vectors. OP probably mentioned two as simple example, but could have unknown count of vectors.

Comment: @Dialecticus  I am sure the OP can generalize it no... My main purpose was to illustrate the use of next_permuation

Comment: Thanks @parapura rajkumar your idea of next_permutation helped me a lot.. thanks

Answer (score -1):

For this problem recursion could be omitted entirely by using `next_permutation`. Here's some untested code that is arguably more elegant:

```
void myPerm(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& myItems)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myItems.size(); i++)
        std::sort(myItems[i].begin(), myItems[i].end());

    int level;

    do
    {
        printAll(myItems);

        level = myItems.size() - 1;

        while (!next_permutation(myItems[level].begin(), myItems[level].end()))
            level--;
    }
    while (level >= 0);
}
```

Nice thing about `next_permutation` is that it returns false as it "wraps around" given set, and so the set is sorted and ready for the next round of permutations.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dialecticus your idea helped me a lot. Thanks i was able to write my own code...Thanks